# Installing Kali Linux on VirtualBox, on boot it stops on a flashing display

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

This is my first time ever using a VM or installing Linux, so it could just be user error; but I've installed Kali on a VM using VirtualBox and have gotten to where tutorials are saying the system will reboot and take me to the root login screen.

However, instead of a login screen, I'm confronted with what looks like some kind of command line with green lines text saying [OK] followed by lines in white, and it keeps flickering to black for a few seconds before returning. I've found that I can type letters, but delete, enter, and backspace don't work. Do I need to re-install? Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT: Screenshot of what keeps flashing is below.

[image: Here's what keeps flashing on screen at startup.]

Comment: @dsstorefile You're right :) I may try for something simpler if the problem is too complicated; but Kali is what was recommended to me for the Cybersecurity-esque things I'm looking at doing, so it'd be great if I could get started, even if the learning curve is a little steep. :)

Comment: @dsstorefile Added an image above :)

Comment: I'm thinking it might be a disk space issue. I'm going to try setting up a new machine with a lot more disk space and seeing if that fixes it.

Comment: @G-Man if you don't have a contribution to solving the problem, then stay out of the question. Moving to close EVERY QUESTION you personally don't have an answer to in Kali/Debian is poor. Are we trying to discourage Kali use? No... We are trying to discourage stupid obvious Kali questions, not discourage information security students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a disk space issue!

I discovered this by hitting alt-f2, typing in the username (root) and password, and tried a solution I found on a forum:

> use alt+f2 and login into a separate terminal session
>
> remove gnome with
>   sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-core gnome-shell gnome-session
>
> reinstall it 
>   sudo apt-get install gnome-core gnome-shell gnome-session
>
> reboot

Upon trying to enter the first "remove gnome" line, though, it gave me a fatal error citing disk space.

I created a new machine and allocated 25GB of disk space this time (as opposed to about 10, which was kind dumb now that I think about it) and it works perfectly fine!